# Lista saindo de ordem durante execução de looping

Tags: python, postgresql, redes

O script abaixo captura as *INTERFACE* de rede de um *HOST*, e insere no banco de dados (POSTGRES), troquei o método do cursor por um print para verificar como estava sendo inserido no banco de dados, e reparei que em terminado quantidade de inserções, os valores que eram para estar na coluna IPV4 estão indo para coluna MAC, acredito que o erro esteja nesse trecho:

```
# insere rede
rows = len(interface) 
rows2 = (len(address) - 1)
rede = 0
MAC = 0
contv4 = 1
contV6 = 2
while rede < rows:
    while contv4 < rows2:
        print("INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');" % (platform.node(),interface[rede],incoming[rede],outgoing[rede],address[MAC],address[contv4],address[contV6],str(timestamp))+"\n")
        rede = rede + 1
        MAC = MAC + 3
        contv4 = contv4 + 3
        contV6 = contV6 + 3
    break
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
import psutil
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading
import itertools
import sys
from psutil._common import bytes2human
import socket
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM
import platform

timestamp = datetime.now()
p = psutil.Process()
address = []
interface = []
incoming = []
outgoing = []
stats = []
broadcast = []
netmask = []
done = False

af_map = {
    socket.AF_INET: 'IPv4',
    socket.AF_INET6: 'IPv6',
    psutil.AF_LINK: 'MAC',
}

duplex_map = {
    psutil.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: "full",
    psutil.NIC_DUPLEX_HALF: "half",
    psutil.NIC_DUPLEX_UNKNOWN: "?",
}

AD = "-"
AF_INET6 = getattr(socket, 'AF_INET6', object())
proto_map = {
    (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM): 'tcp',
    (AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM): 'tcp6',
    (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM): 'udp',
    (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM): 'udp6',
}

def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rCarregando, aguarde por favor... ' + c + '\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

def agent_colect():

# REDE
    stats = psutil.net_if_stats()
    io_counters = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
    for nic, addrs in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
        interface.append("%s:" % (nic))
        if nic in io_counters:
            io = io_counters[nic]
            incoming.append("bytes=%s, pkts=%s, errs=%s, drops=%s" % (
                bytes2human(io.bytes_recv), io.packets_recv, io.errin,
                io.dropin))
            outgoing.append("bytes=%s, pkts=%s, errs=%s, drops=%s" % (
                bytes2human(io.bytes_sent), io.packets_sent, io.errout,
                io.dropout))
        for addr in addrs:
            address.append(af_map.get(addr.family)+" "+addr.address)
            if addr.broadcast:
                broadcast.append("         broadcast : %s" % addr.broadcast)
            if addr.netmask:
                netmask.append("         netmask   : %s" % addr.netmask)
    # insere rede
    rows = len(interface) 
    rows2 = (len(address) - 1)
    rede = 0
    MAC = 0
    contv4 = 1
    contV6 = 2
    while rede < rows:
        while contv4 < rows2:
            print("INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');" % (platform.node(),interface[rede],incoming[rede],outgoing[rede],address[MAC],address[contv4],address[contV6],str(timestamp))+"\n")
            rede = rede + 1
            MAC = MAC + 3
            contv4 = contv4 + 3
            contV6 = contV6 + 3
        break

    done = True
    return done

load = threading.Thread(target=animate)
load.start()
worker = threading.Thread(target=agent_colect)
done = agent_colect()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','vEthernet (DockerNAT):','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=1.1M, pkts=6654, errs=0, drops=0','MAC 00-15-5D-38-01-20','IPv4 10.0.75.1','IPv6 fe80::9de9:8978:cfc4:d262','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','ConexÒo de Rede Bluetooth:','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','MAC 04-D3-B0-C2-A9-6F','IPv4 169.254.240.79','IPv6 fe80::b1c5:80a9:f354:f04f','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:','bytes=38.0B, pkts=38, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=4.6K, pkts=4699, errs=0, drops=0','MAC 00-50-56-C0-00-08','IPv4 192.168.233.1','IPv6 fe80::4d79:a42e:a656:feb','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','vEthernet (Default Switch):','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=803.6K, pkts=3696, errs=0, drops=0','MAC 02-15-B7-9D-2F-F3','IPv4 192.168.187.1','IPv6 fe80::60b9:8a8c:d43f:9402','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','VirtualBox Host-Only Network:','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','MAC 0A-00-27-00-00-0A','IPv4 192.168.56.1','IPv6 fe80::741e:194f:1bc4:54b8','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:','bytes=38.0B, pkts=38, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=1.4K, pkts=1436, errs=0, drops=0','MAC 00-50-56-C0-00-01','IPv4 192.168.199.1','IPv6 fe80::c490:5dfc:8b51:3fd6','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1:','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','IPv4 127.0.0.1','IPv6 ::1','MAC 64-1C-67-A3-C1-1C','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','Ethernet:','bytes=234.1M, pkts=340631, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=22.8M, pkts=130525, errs=0, drops=0','IPv4 9.18.235.171','IPv6 fe80::6569:4181:ab3c:721c','MAC 04-D3-B0-C2-A9-6B','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','Wi-Fi:','bytes=58.2K, pkts=414, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=121.7K, pkts=852, errs=0, drops=0','IPv4 9.86.236.141','IPv6 fe80::69e4:d30d:fa99:b325','MAC 06-D3-B0-C2-A9-6B','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');

INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) VALUES('DESKTOP-USER','ConexÒo Local* 2:','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','bytes=0.0B, pkts=0, errs=0, drops=0','IPv4 169.254.151.189','IPv6 fe80::ccd7:4c4d:8a4f:97bd','MAC 04-D3-B0-C2-A9-6C','2019-08-28 13:11:08.806000');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando inserir seus dados de texto diretamente na query, e está acotnecendo o equivalente a um 'SQL injection" aí - simplesmente uma das strings de texto que você está colocando na query inclui um caracter `'`. Como você está interpolando a string do no seu código, sem nenhum cuidado de escapar ou sanitizar os dados, a query está quebrando.

O Python resolve esse problema há, possivelmente décadas (no plural), delegando a interpolação de dados nas queries de SQL para acontecerem *dentro* da chamada `.execute` do driver de SQL. A sintaxe, dependendo do driver, é *muito parecida* com a interpolação direta - no caso usando o `%` - que você está usando, mas desse jeito aí, o Python executa a expressão entre parênteses, constrói a string incorreta com o operador `%`, e depois chama o método `.execute`. O correto é passar os mesmos argumentos, mas como um argumento para a função .execute - e deixar a interpolação de string acontecer lá dentro.

Agora, na hora de escrever o exemplo, percebi que vocẽ **não está** se conectando ao banco de dados pelo Python - está imprimendo as queries em stdout e usando pipe para consumir as queries.

Não é, nem de longe, a melhor forma de fazer isso - talvez o maior motivo seja justamente que você perde a interpolação de parâmetros do driver de Python do Postgresql - além de perder outras otimizações e checagens de segurança.

SE você estivesse usando o Python da forma normal, se conectaria ao Postgresql com  o driver psycopg2, a sua query seria executada como:

```
    ...
    connection.execute("""INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts
         (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta)
         VALUES({},{},{},{},{},{},{},{})""",(
         platform.node(),interface[rede],incoming[rede],
         outgoing[rede],address[MAC],address[contv4],
         address[contV6],str(timestamp)
    )
```

(observe como o uso de strings triplas, e quebrar o statement em várias linhas 
facilita também, mas isso é algo a parte do problema principal)

Bom, a recomendação **forte** que fica é você alterar seu programa para se conectar usando um driver de postgresql, em vez de usar stdout para isso.

Se por algum motivo você insistir nessa aborgagem de costurar as coisas 
pelo shell, será necessário no mínimo escapar todos os `'` dentro das suas strings - para manter curto, é possível fazer isso como uma comprehension:

```py
  print ("""INSERT INTO tbl_rede_hosts \
         (hostname,interface_rede,incoming,outcoing,mac,ipv4,ipv6,data_coleta) \
         VALUES({},{},{},{},{},{},{},{});\n""".format(
             *(parameter.replace("'", "''") for parameter in (
                  platform.node(),interface[rede],incoming[rede],
                  outgoing[rede],address[MAC],address[contv4],
                  address[contV6],str(timestamp)) )
   )
```

Comment: Gostei da sua explicação ficou bem didática, porém eu fui testar como vc disse, e entrou em um looping a execução, conseguiria me enviar o script que você formulou ?

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações e deu certo, muito obrigado amigo!